# Dialects classification using deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, classification, applications, voice-recognition

Dialects differ a lot between cities in my country, Syria. People sometimes express themselves using different local phrases and idioms which refer to the same topic. So, I came up with the idea of creating an Android application shows a limited set of sentences or expressions while asking you to express them in the local dialect of your region **orally**, after that this application tries to figure out what your dialect is. For a short period of time, I'm going to launch an Android application in order to collect the needed dataset which will be a new contribution. First of all, I need some helpful answers to my questions:

1. In general, is a period of 6 months enough for such a project to be done by only one student who is a **beginner in this field** or it is harder than it seems?
2. Are the libraries and tools needed to do this project available for free?
3. I know that more training data leads to more accurate results. In order to obtain good results, what is the estimated minimum number of training data needed for this model?
4. How do you advise me to begin?
5. How much is my suggested project relevant to the project attached in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition)?

kindly write down your suggested edits and recommendations if any.

**Edit** for the 5th question: also see [this](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1707/1707.09917.pdf) paper.

Comment: I think that your project is interesting, but if you have never implemented anything using any ML library/framework before, then it will take you sometime first to get used to the libraries. It also depends on your programming background. It's hard to answer your questions. We don't know what you know about ML. If you really don't know anything, then maybe this project is quite challenge (I would say). Anyway, I think it will not be easy to give you satisfactory answers to all of your questions.

Comment: @nbro Yes, I'm a very beginner student in this field. However, I have a strong background in algorithms and data structs using the C++ programming language. Can you answer 2, 3 or 5, please! Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: You will be luckier if you ask just one question per post. If you ask multiple questions, then the users will be discouraged because an eventual answer to your questions might come up to be very long, or they might know the answer to one question but not the others, etc. So, ideally, you should try to ask questions which should not produce very long answers.

Comment: Anyway, I think that the answer to your 2nd question is "yes, there are free tools which will help you to implement such system or most of it".

Comment: Answered the same question at https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11116/how-much-the-dialects-recognition-and-speech-recognition-are-relevant