# How much the dialects recognition and speech recognition are relevant?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, classification, voice-recognition

In [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition) tutorial, they build a speech recognition model to classify a one-second audio clip as one of ten predefined words. Suppose that we modified this problem as the following: Given an Arabic dataset, we aim to build a *dialects* recognition model to classify a *two*-second audio clip as one of $n$ local dialects using ten predefined *sentences*. I.e. for each of these ten sentences, there are $x$ different phrases and idioms which refer to the same meaning$^*$. Now how can I take advantage of the mentioned tutorial to solve the modified problem?

$*$ The $x$ different phrases and idioms for each sentence are not predefined.

Comment: Is my modified problem similar to this [one](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1707/1707.09917.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorials you link are not much relevant, there are already existing implementations of your exact problem.

You can use https://github.com/swshon/dialectID_e2e, there are many other similar implementations on github.

Comment: Can you explain more how they are not relevant? Thank you.

Comment: You can use those things too, they are just not as related as the project I linked you.